# Show that the finite complement topology is connected

Tags: general-topology

I am looking at $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the finite complement topology and need to show it's connected.

I know that a connected doesn't have any non-trivial clopen sets. 
For $U \in T$ where T is the topology I done $\mathbb{R}^n$ complement the union of all the $U$'s to get the intersection of $\mathbb{R}^n$ complement all the U's. We know this is closed because the U's are open. Then, I did the same vice versa and got that the union of $\mathbb{R}^n$ complement all the U's as closed. Therefore I found no nontrivial clopen subsets. I was wondering if I have done this right and if not how can my answer or method be improved?

Comment: It is not clear what you say when you describe your argument... However, you have simply to notice that if you have a non-trivial clopen $U$, then $U$ is finite and $U^C$ is finite as well. So you have $\Bbb{R}=U \cup U^C$ is finite, and this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction: Notice that $\Bbb R^n$ is infinite. If it wasn't connected, you get $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ non-empty, open, and disjoint sets such that $\Bbb R^n = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$. However: $$\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2 = \varnothing \implies \Omega_1 \subset \Bbb R^n \setminus \Omega_2, \quad \text{and}\quad \Omega_{2}\subset \Bbb R^n \setminus \Omega_1.$$
Since $\Omega_1,\Omega_2 \neq \varnothing$ and we're dealing with the cofinite topology, then $\Bbb R^n \setminus \Omega_1$ and $\Bbb R^n \setminus \Omega_2$ are both finite. By the above, $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are finite themselves. Hence $\Bbb R^n = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$ is finite, a contradiction.

The above argument holds for any space $(X, \tau)$ with the cofinite topology (countable complement topology), given that $X$ is infinite (uncountable).

Comment: I don't understand how showing it's finite shows that it is connected?

Comment: I should have phrased it better... I proved that the cofinife topology is connected by contradiction. If it is not connected, you conclude that $\Bbb R^n$ is finite.

Comment: Actually it is sufficient that the space is infinite, you don't need that it is uncountable to be connected.

Comment: Yes, I'll give the answer a little edit.